# When a value is declared "by lazy" in Kotlin is that phrase always optional?

Tags: kotlin

If I simply remove all "by lazy" initializations in a Kotlin program will the program keep the same semantics? By the same semantics, I mean program logic will remain the same, although various initializations may occur in a different time or sequence than before.

Comment: In an Android app where you need to initialize everything in `onCreate` or later, but not in the constructor, you would definitely run into problems with the removal of lazy initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your program as some side effects the answer is no.

So the short answer to your question is no. Example

```
class Foo {
  var anyValue: String = ""

  private val bar by lazy { Bar(anyValue) }

   /**
   * Here depending when this method get called the value of
   * anyValue may have changed so the behavior of bar.
   */
  fun doSomeThingWithBar(){
      bar.doSomething()
  }

}
```